# Check if the browser supports document.querySelectorAll in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, cross-browser, document

Now although most modern browser support `document.querySelectorAll()`, you may run into problems with older versions of Internet Explorer. The obvious way of checking if the browser supports a function would be:

```
if(document.querySelectorAll){
    //some random code
}
```

But from what I understand some browsers like (IE8) don't support certain properties, like '`body *`'. Is there a better way to check if `document.querySelectorAll('body *')` will actually work?

Comment: IE8 supports CSS2 selectors only, but wouldn't `body *` be a CSS2 selector ?

Comment: Exactly that's the problem I'm having. I am looking for a way to test this.

Comment: What does `body *` do in IE8?

Comment: I don't think you understood, wouldn't `body *` work in IE8, it looks like a CSS2 selector to me, and should work ?

Comment: What says the console?

Comment: It should work in IE7+ http://caniuse.com/css-sel2

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462057.aspx#selectorapi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` will thrown on any unsupported selector so you can simply use a `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 4):

Check browser supports or not , without try-catch :

```
function QuerySelectors() {
  return (document['querySelector']&&document['querySelectorAll'])!=null;
}
```

or

```
function QuerySelectors(){
  return typeof(document['querySelector'])=='function'&&typeof(document['querySelectorAll'])=='function';
}
```

Read more > [Reference](http://htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/using-javascripts-css3-selectors.html)

Answer (score -2):

Use **typeof** to check it:

```
 if(typeof(document.querySelectorAll) != 'undefined'){
      //some random code
 }
```