# JavaScript: querySelector Null vs querySelector

Tags: javascript, selection

What is the main difference between these two methods of referencing?

What are the benefits of using one or the other? Also what kind of usage-case would they each be best suited to?

```
var selection = document.querySelector('.selector') !== null;

var selection = document.querySelector('.selector');
```

Is the former solely for browser legacy support?

Comment: Well, the first one returns boolean value, the second one returns an object or null. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: yes, perhaps a little more in-depth though. What is a boolean value? and what's the difference between it and an object?

Comment: Boolean is another word for "true/false".

Comment: also [you can check](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22286844) `querySelector` supports in client browser or not **!**

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The first one gets the reference and checks if the element exists, and saves this status as a boolean value in the variable. If the element exists, the variable contains `true` otherwise `false`.

You would use the first one if you only want to know if the element exists, but don't need the reference to it.

Example:

```
var selection = document.querySelector('.selector') !== null;
if (selection) {
  alert('The element exists in the page.');
} else {
  alert('The element does not exists in the page.');
}
```

The second one gets the reference and stores in the variable, but doesn't check if the element exists. If the element exists, the variable contains the reference to the element, otherwise the variable contains `null`.

You would use the second one if you need the reference to the element. If it's possible that the element doesn't exist in the page, you should check if the variable contains `null` before you try to do something with the reference.

Example:

```
var selection = document.querySelector('.selector');
if (selection !== null) {
  alert('I have a reference to a ' + selection.tagName + ' element.');
} else {
  alert('The element does not exists in the page.');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you could also do:

```
[].filter.call([document.querySelector('.single-selected-class')], item => item)
    .forEach(item => item.blur());
```

Answer (score 3):

The first statement contains a bool value depends on `document.querySelector('.selector')` is null or not

```
var selection = document.querySelector('.selector') !== null;
```

the second statement contains the actual value of `document.querySelector('.selector');`

```
var selection = document.querySelector('.selector');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to avoid the conditional statement with:

```
var selection = document.querySelectorAll('.selector');
selection.forEach(function(item) {
    alert(item);
});
```

**Caution!** `querySelectorAll()` behaves differently than most common JavaScript DOM libraries, which might lead to unexpected results

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

I was developing a similar solution for CMS EFFCORE and came up with the following:

```
if (!Node.prototype.hasOwnProperty('querySelector__withHandler')) {
    Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, 'querySelector__withHandler', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable  : true,
        writable    : true,
        value: function (query, handler) {
            var result = this.querySelector(query);
            if (result instanceof Node) {
                handler(result);
            }
        }
    });
}

document.querySelector__withHandler('a', function(link){
    alert(link)
})
```