# How to handle 'queryselected' element that are not in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I'm creating a multipage website that doesn't share the same layout, and by using a single javascript file the console throws an error every time an element is not in the DOM. I'm looking for a solution that avoids me to include every bit of code in an `if` statement that check if the element exists.

e.g.

### Javascript file

```
let myelement = document.querySelector('.myelement');
let myelementText = myelement.textContent;

console.log(myelementText);
```

### HTML template #1

```html
<ul>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
</ul>
```

**Console output for template #1**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
    at window.onload ((index):33)
```

### HTML template #2

```html
<ul>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li class="myelement">Element</li>
</ul>
```

**Console output for template #2**

```
element
```

### Current - and hopefully - avoidable solution

```
let myelement = document.querySelector('.myelement');
if (typeof (myelement) != 'undefined' && myelement != null) {
  let myelementText = myelement.textContent;

  console.log(myelementText);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around to check if the element exists. You can remove the `typeof undefined` check, a check for `!= null` should be enough.

Where you implement this check is up to you, you can use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987071/javascript-queryselector-null-vs-queryselector) to not select myelement in the first case.

```
if (document.querySelector('.myelement') !== null) {
  alert('The element "myelement" exists in the page.');
} else {
  alert('The element "myelement" does not exists in the page.');
}
```

```js
let myelement = document.querySelector('.myelement');
if (myelement != null) {
  let myelementText = myelement.textContent;

  console.log(myelementText);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
</ul>
```