# Shorten querySelector and style change

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

Is there a way to shorten querySelector result and perform an operation on its result? Ideally in one line?

Imagine having an element:

`<div id="el">A</div>`

And corresponding JavaScript code:

```
const el = document.querySelector("#el");

el ? el.style.display = "none" : null;
```

Assuming `div#el` may or may not be rendered on the page (hence ternary operator), is there a way to shorten above logic to one line?

Comment: I think the only way is to not create `const` and use it directly in short code. if you need `const` your method is already the best

Comment: You can do `document.querySelector("#el")?.style.setProperty("display", "none")`. But why do you need to shorten that code int he first place? This starts getting into the realm of hacks.

Answer (score 0):

why not just

```
if (document.querySelector("#el")) document.querySelector("#el").style.display = "none"
```

You don't need to do anything if the if doesn't match so I don't see the point of using a ternary

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ternary side effects.

An if is easer to read

```js
const el = document.getElementById("el");
if (el) el.hidden=true;
```

```html
<div id="el">A</div>
```

Shorter for same result:

```css
#el { display: none }
```

```html
<div id="el">A</div>
```

Oneliner

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#el").forEach(el => el.hidden=true);
```

```html
<div id="el">A</div>
```

Comment: Whoever voted my CSS only down should look again

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing `Maybe` is good for

```
const maybeSelect = selector => {
   const elem = document.querySelector(selector);
   return elem ? Just(elem) : Nothing();
};
```

```
maybeSelect('#el').effect(x => x.style.display = 'none');
```

A simplistic (awful) implementation

```
const Just = (value) => ({
   fold: (f = x => x) => f(value),
   map: f => Just(f(value)),
   effect: f => (f(value), Just(value))
})

const Nothing = () => ({
   fold: () => null,
   map: f => Nothing(),
   effect: f => Nothing()
})
```

Basically when you use `effect` on a `Nothing`, it does nothing, and whether you have a `Nothing` or a `Just` is decided in `maybeSelect`.

`map` allows you to transform the value and `fold` to retrieve it.

And of course you can chain `effect`s and `map`s at will.

It may seem a bit overkill, but once you get used to it, it's addictive.

You can turn to libraries such as [Folktale](https://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.3.0/en/folktale.maybe.fromnullable.html) if you are interested.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I found a one-liner

```
[].filter.call([document.querySelector('#el')], el => el).forEach(el => el.style.display = "none");
```

Taken from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42532205/10684798

Comment: original: 73 chars; yours 92

Comment: A querySelector only returns one item, so you can't iterate, maybe this solution coulb be good for `querySelectorAll`, which returns an array

Comment: @Del it is wrapped in array?