# Console error with append child when element doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I have the following code inside a timeout function which works fine when the element exists, but when it doesn't, it throws a console error (and is breaking something else on the page as a result)

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  // moves #dashboard_basket_btn into #dashboard_basket
  var dashboard_basket = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket');
  var dashboard_basket_card = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket_btn');
  dashboard_basket.appendChild(dashboard_basket_card);
  dashboard_basket_card.classList.add('show_important');
}, 2500);
```

When #dashboard_basket_btn doesn't exist (it's sometimes loaded in dynamically, not always on usual page load), the part of the appendChild function where it references dashboard_basket_card says that parameter 1 is not of type: Node (guessing that means it doesn't exist?)

Is there a clever way of handing this or for it not to get upset if the element doesn't exist at the time the function runs?

Comment: What is the problem to just add an if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you can check whether the element exists or not, For example

```
var dashboard_basket_card_exists = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket_btn') !== null; //the value will be true if it exists or false, if it isn't.

var dashboard_basket_exists = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket') !== null;
```

After that, you can write a regular if statement, Like

```
if(dashboard_basket_card_exists && dashboard_basket_exists)
{
 var dashboard_basket = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket');
 var dashboard_basket_card = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket_btn');
 dashboard_basket.appendChild(dashboard_basket_card);
 dashboard_basket_card.classList.add('show_important');
}
```

This is one way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional chaining operator in conjunction with the logical and operator.

```
dashboard_basket_card 
  && 
 dashboard_basket?.appendChild(dashboard_basket_card).classList.add('show_important');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it exists first?

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // moves #dashboard_basket_btn into #dashboard_basket
if(document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket')!=undefined &&
document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket_btn')!=undefined){
var dashboard_basket = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket');
    var dashboard_basket_card = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket_btn');
    dashboard_basket.appendChild(dashboard_basket_card);
    dashboard_basket_card.classList.add('show_important');
 
}
 }, 2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `if` and check if both exist

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var dashboard_basket = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket');
  var dashboard_basket_card = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket_btn');
  if (dashboard_basket && dashboard_basket_card) {
    dashboard_basket.appendChild(dashboard_basket_card);
    dashboard_basket_card.classList.add('show_important');
  }
}, 2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if() {}` statement and simply check if the element exists. With `!!` (double negation) you convert a value to a boolean, for example `undefined` to `false` or an (existing) `object` to `true`.

**Working example:** (*run the snippet to see no errormessage*)

```js
if ( !!document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket') && !!document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket_btn') ) {
  var dashboard_basket = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket');
  var dashboard_basket_card = document.querySelector('#dashboard_basket_btn');
  dashboard_basket.appendChild(dashboard_basket_card);
  dashboard_basket_card.classList.add('show_important');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript: querySelector Null vs querySelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987071/javascript-queryselector-null-vs-queryselector)

Also following line you can try:

> typeof(queried variable) === "undefined"