# Filter product price using input range and render in the DOM

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me to solve my problem with filtering. I'm trying to filter the products price using the input range slider. I have an array state which I stored all the products coming from the API. My problem is when I move the slider it doesn't move and when I move the slider to the left the products array starts to filter the items where price is less than equal to the input range value. Another problem is when I move the range slider to the right the products array doesn't filter anymore. I'm trying to render it but it doesn't render. I'm using publisher-subscriber pattern for filtering the price.

**model.js**

```
export const state = {
  products: [],
};

export const loadAllProducts = async function () {
  try {
    const data = await getJSON(`${API_URL}`);
    state.products = data.map(product => {
      return {
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name,
        image: product.image,
        brand: product.company,
        category: product.category,
        price: product.price,
      };
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const loadFilterPrice = function (value) {
  const filtered = state.products.filter(product => product.price <= value);

  if (filtered.length < 1) throw new Error('Sorry, no products matched your search!');

  state.products = filtered;
  console.log(state.products);
};
```

**productsView.js** This function is for filtering the product price. Publisher-subscriber pattern.

```
addHandlerFilterPrice(handler) {
  this._parentElement.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    const priceFilter = e.target.closest('.price__filter');
    const priceText = document.querySelector('.price__text');
    const value = parseInt(priceFilter.value);

    if (!priceFilter) return;

    priceFilter.value = value;
    priceText.textContent = formatPrice(value);
    handler(value);
  });
}
```

**Controller**

```
import * as model from '../model';
import ProductsView from '../Views/productsView';


//This is for rendering all the products
const controlProducts = async function () {
  try {
    ProductsView.renderSpinner();
    await model.loadAllProducts();
    ProductsView.render(model.state.products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`${error} `);
  }
};

//This is for filtering the products by price using the input range slider
const controlFilterPrice = function (value) {
  try {
    model.loadFilterPrice(value);
    ProductsView.render(model.state.products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`${error} `);
  }
};

const init = () => {
  controlProducts();
  ProductsView.addHandlerFilterPrice(controlFilterPrice);
};

init();
```

**This is how I render the product. I call this _generateMarkup in the parent class**

```
_generateMarkup() {
  return /*html*/ `
    <a
      href="${detailsPage}&id=${this._data.id}"
      class="relative flex flex-col overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-customSm transition duration-300 hover:shadow-lg"
    >
      <figure class="relative h-48 sm:h-52 xl:h-44 w-full overflow-hidden xl:w-full">
        <img
          src="${this._data.image}"
          alt="${this._data.name}"
          class="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full object-cover object-center transition duration-300 hover:scale-105"
        />
      </figure>
      <div class="flex flex-col">
        <div class="px-6 pb-8 pt-6">
          <span
            class="mb-3 inline-block rounded-full bg-amber-100 px-3 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase tracking-wider text-amber-500"
            >${this._data.brand}</span
          >
          <h4 class="mb-2 border-b pb-3 text-base font-bold uppercase text-neutral-600">
            ${this._data.name}
          </h4>
          <div class="mt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
            <div class="flex items-baseline space-x-1 text-amber-500">
              <p class="text-lg font-medium">${formatPrice(this._data.price)}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center space-x-3">
              <button class="icon h-6 w-6" aria-label="Add to Wishlist">
                <svg class="h-5 w-5 fill-current">
                  <use xlink:href="${icons}#icon-wishlist"></use>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  `;
}
```

Comment: Please help me guys

Comment: provide your code via codesandbox

Comment: I'm having a problem with running my code in codesandbox. I don't know why it's not running in codesandbox.

Comment: Please help me guys. Thanks!